# pass CoreData ObjectId as a parameter in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Can I pass ObjectId as a parameter in my iPad app?

I'd like to pass [MyObject objectID] as my parameter and look up the object based on this in Core Data.

Comment: You have the object, however you choose to use the ID of the object to be able to retrieve it later on? Why not just pass it as the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly do that, though the receiving object needs an `NSManagedObjectContext` to be able to look up the object again.